# Html table with first fixed row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make table with first fixed row. My markup is:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    ....
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I set up `overflow` and `max-height` for `tbody`, but scroll doesn't occurs. It occurs if i will add `display:block` to the `tbody`, but in this way i'll get tbody with width = tableWidth / 2, how to make tbody `display : block` and full width?

Comment: personally i would recommend not doing this with a table. i would recommend using `div`s and/or `ul`+`li` as you'll have a much nicer time with alignment and spacing. however, SW4's solution is probably the best you'll get with a table

Answer (score 4):

If Im right in thinking what you want to do, try the below.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/nyCKE/3702/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Header1</td>
            <td>Header2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width:100%;
}
tbody {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
td {
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
thead > tr, tbody {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: this wont work nicely if he needs multiple columns as each column will then scroll individually

Comment: +1.. not sure if it's better or worse.. but to maintain spacing auto-magically with the columns you could use some `text-align:justify` goodness.. http://jsfiddle.net/UEZj8/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the css below on the row that you want fixed :

**CSS**

```
style="position:fixed;top:0;background:#FFF;"
```

**Example** : http://jsfiddle.net/V84PE/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `first-child` for this:

```
table tr:first-child td {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

You can also use `last-child`.

More css features: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048